# apache rewrite unless condition met

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I'm trying to set up Apache (2.4.25 on Amazon Linux) to redirect users to a certain site if their remote address is NOT in a given list of authorized IP addresses. For example, if their IP address is `123.321.123.1` or `192.192.192.5` or within `169.22.123.x`, then proceed to `mysite.com`; otherwise, redirect to `google.com`.

I'm not sure how to handle this aside from knowing that it will involve shenanigans with Rewrite, which I'm comfortable doing.

Any help or suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: You can use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check the content of `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` to make the following RewriteRule conditional.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, but what I'm really unsure about is how to specify the range of acceptable IP addresses.

Comment: Well for the full IP addresses you can use the `'=CondPattern'` syntax, and matching addresses starting with `169.22.123.` can be done using a very basic regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you're on 2.4!

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '123.321.123.1' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} ==  '192.192.192.5' || -R '169.22.123.0/24'">
  Redirect /what /matched
</If>
```